# Choosing proper database for a few users application

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, sqlite, sql-server-ce

Requirements:

- tiny WinForms client app (C# 4.0, WinForms or WPF)
- a few users working simultinausly
- no database service at all - the whole engine as *.DLLs inside client
  apps
- database available as shared folder on one computer
- at least simple concurrrency checks
- compatible with nHibernate or EntityFramework / NET 4.0
- backup as simple as copying files from shared folder - assuming no
  running clients at the moment
- no stored procedures/triggers required
- data size - a few tables and a few thousands rows after 2 years

Nice to have:

- user access rights
- encrypted data

I'm trying to choose between:

- MS Access
- SqlLite
- SqlServer Compact Edition.

Can you recommend which one should be the best for these requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all your limited criteria, limited rows within a few years, it appears to be what I would consider a "disposable" application.  Whatever is quickest and easiest would probably be Access

Comment: Also with access, moving data between applications is easy and there is a great deal of documentation.

Comment: Jet/ACE (not Access) also has the advantage of being installed on ever Windows PC with Win2000 or higher, so there's no installation/configuration issue.

Comment: 'disposable application' - yes, exactly it could be like this.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite can be a good option for this. It hasa very small footprint. But you can also look at [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) as well. I am however yet to see the support for Entity Framework et al.

Comment: I would prefer SqlLite but the businness requirements for using MS Access were stronger.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is a good alternative, but you should setup it correctly.

Have a look here:

[How Scalable is SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998/how-scalable-is-sqlite)