# SQLite: import float data from the CSV file as numeric with sqlite3.exe utility

Tags: csv, import, sqlite

I use [Command Line Shell For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) on Windows within Git Bash console.

Let there be products.csv file in the working directory

```
name,price
"product A",125.00
"product B",8.99
"product C",20.50
"product D",109.99
```

I do import to a new products table

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import products.csv products
```

I check table schema. The `price` column is TEXT

```
sqlite> .schema products
CREATE TABLE products(
  "name" TEXT,
  "price" TEXT
);
```

As the result ordering records by price is alphabetical

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price;
"product D",109.99
"product A",125.00
"product C",20.50
"product B",8.99
```

**How to change the price column type to float in SQLite3?**

P.S. The [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240315/how-to-import-csv-file-to-sqlite-with-correct-data-types)  does not work for me (I tried REAL, NUMERIC and FLOAT).

```
sqlite> UPDATE products SET price = CAST(price AS REAL);
sqlite> .schema products
CREATE TABLE products(
  "name" TEXT,
  "price" TEXT
);
```

Comment: You could create the table ahead of time. "create table products(name text, price float)" and then perform the import.

Comment: @Todd It worked for me. Would you mind adding answer.

Comment: Glad it worked. Added as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the table first and then import into the table. SQLite will import any headers as a data row when you do this so delete before hand or delete from table afterward.

```
create table products(name text, price float);
.mode csv
.import newproducts.csv products
```

where newproducts.csv is file without headers

```
"product A",125.00
"product B",8.99
"product C",20.50
"product D",109.99
```

Answer (score 1):

Values in CSV files are always imported as strings.

You have to create the table with the types you want, and to change the types afterwards:

```
UPDATE products
SET price = CAST(price AS NUMERIC);
```

Comment: I've already tried it. It does not change table. Rows are still ordered alphabetically.