# python import csv to sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

Hi i am trying to import a csv file to a sqlite3 database using python tkinter.
 I open file using askopenfilename dialog and pass the file to readFile function.

```
def csvFile(self):
        f1 = askopenfilename()
       self.readFile(f1)

def readFile(self, filename):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Unicommerce.db')
    cur = conn.cursor() 
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unicom(products varchar,channel varchar,regulatory_forms varchar,shipment varchar)""")
    filename.encode('utf-8')
    print "test1"
    reader = csv.reader(filename)
    for field in reader:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO unicom VALUES (?,?,?,?);", field)

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I am getting this error.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO unicom VALUES (?,?,?,?);", field)
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 4, and there are 1 supplied.
```

I tried every possoible solution available but couldn't import file to database.

I also tried tried solutions given in these links 
[Importing a CSV file into a sqlite3 database table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python)
[Python CSV to SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942402/python-csv-to-sqlite)

EDIT: Link to input file [Input File](http://tempsend.com/95CCA02D39)

Comment: This error means that there's not enough values in `field` to match your expression. Try adding `print repr(field)` before your SQL command to see what `field` actually contains.

Comment: It would be simpler if you could supply some example of your input data!

Comment: It is printing this --  ['C'] . I included my input file. Check edit

Comment: There is only one item in the list what do you expect it would thourh error

Comment: How can i rectify the error?

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the csv file you're using and the code of the function `askopenfilename` ?

Comment: Check edit on Question. I have added a link to file at bottom of question

Comment: What does askopenfilename does ? It looks like you're trying to use reader with the filename of the csv when it wants the file object (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader). You need to open the file before giving it to reader.
Try `reader = csv.reader(open(filename, "r"))`

Comment: I am using tkinter for gui. askopenfilename open a file dialog where i select the file and then pass it to readFile method

Comment: Thanks i used     open(filename) and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file before you pass it to `csv.reader`. Heres a basic runnable example that works. I added a class to allow your existing methods to be used as is.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

class csvrd(object):
    def csvFile(self):

        self.readFile('Labels.csv')

    def readFile(self, filename):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Unicommerce.db')
        cur = conn.cursor() 
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unicom(products varchar,channel varchar,regulatory_forms varchar,shipment varchar)""")
        filename.encode('utf-8')
        print "test1"
        with open(filename) as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for field in reader:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO unicom VALUES (?,?,?,?);", field)

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

c = csvrd().csvFile()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Pandas:

```js
import pandas
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite")

conn.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Data (Column1 TEXT, Column2 TEXT)")

df = pandas.read_csv("test.csv")
df.to_sql("Data", conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

`execute` can work thus:

1. `cur.execute("INSERT INTO unicom VALUES (value1,value2, value3,value4);")` where `value1..4` is correct text representation of your data.
2. `cur.execute("INSERT INTO unicom VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", [value1,value2, value3,value4]` where `value1..4` in `list` and db driver liable about correct interpretation main data types.

Ok, because I can't view your data, I would something as below:

```
for field in reader:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO unicom VALUES (?,?,?,?);",\
    field.slpit(my_separator)) #create list with 4 elements for second execute argument
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a library which I have used to convert my csv into sqlite database very easily.

It is [csv2sqlite](https://github.com/rufuspollock/csv2sqlite).

Run: csv2sqlite.py {csv-file-path} {sqlite-db-path} [{table-name}] in terminal.

Make sure your database has the same columns numbers as per the csv.

Hope it helps.

Thank you.