# Inserting billions of data to Sqlite via Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to insert billions of values(exchange rates) to a sqlite db file. I want to use threading because it takes a lot of time but threading pool loop executes same nth element multiple times. I have a print statement in the begining of my method and it prints out multiple times instead of just one.

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2500)

def gen_nums(i, cur):
    global x
    print('row number', x, ' has started')
    gen_numbers = list(mydata)
    sql_data = []
    for f in gen_numbers:
        sql_data.append((f, i, mydata[i]))
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO numbers (rate, min, max) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', sql_data)
    print('row number', x, ' has finished')
    x += 1


with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    for i in mydata:
        pool.submit(gen_nums, i, cur)

pool.shutdown(wait=True)
```

and the output is:

```
row number 1  has started
row number 1  has started
row number 1  has started
row number 1  has started
row number 1  has started
row number 1  has started
row number 1  has started
...
```

Comment: There's no point in using threads; only one will be able to insert rows at a time, making it effectively serial.

Answer (score 2):

Divide your data into chunks on the fly using generator expressions, make inserts inside the transaction.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942402/python-csv-to-sqlite/7137270#7137270) how your code may look like.

Also, sqlite has an ability to [import CSV files.](https://www2.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles)

Sqlite can do tens of [thousands of inserts per second](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19), just make sure to do all of them in a single transaction by surrounding the inserts with BEGIN and COMMIT. (executemany() does this automatically.)

As always, don't optimize before you know speed will be a problem. Test the easiest solution first, and only optimize if the speed is unacceptable.