# How to load a CSV into a sqlite DB using csv headers as table columns using python

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, shelve

I have a csv file for all the plane crash incidents since 1908. The csv header columns are,

```
Date,Time,Location,Operator,Flight #,Route,Type,Registration,cn/In,Aboard,Fatalities,Ground,Summary
```

My code is below, but this prints the entire file,
is there a way using CSV or shelve module using which I can make a persistent db.
End goal here is to do a slice and dice on the data,
eg: sort by date, group by year etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS air_disaster')
cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE "air_disaster" (
    "Date1" TEXT,
    "Time1" TEXT,
    "Location1" TEXT,
    "Operator1" TEXT,
    "Flight_No" TEXT,
    "Route" TEXT,
    "Type1" TEXT,
    "Registration" TEXT,
    "cn" TEXT,
    "Aboard" REAL,
    "Fatalities" REAL,
    "ground" TEXT,
    "Summary" TEXT
)
''')

with  open("/Users/foobar/Downloads/Airplane_Crashes_and_Fatalities_Since_1908.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
 
        Date1 = row["Date"]
        Time1 = row["Time"]
        Location1 = row["Location"]
        Operator1 = row["Operator"]
        Flight_No = row["Flight #"]
        Route = row["Route"]
        Type1 = row["Type"]
        Registration = row["Registration"]
        cn = row["cn/In"]
        Aboard = row["Aboard"]
        Fatalities = row["Fatalities"]
        ground = row["Ground"]
        Summary = row["Summary"]
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO air_disaster(Date1,Time1,Location1,Operator1,Flight_No,Route,Type1,Registration,cn,Aboard,Fatalities,ground,Summary)
        VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', (Date1,Time1,Location1,Operator1,Flight_No,Route,Type1,Registration,cn,Aboard,Fatalities,ground,Summary))
        conn.commit()
    (cur.execute('SELECT * from air_disaster where Fatalities > 1000'))
```

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942402/python-csv-to-sqlite

Comment: I have a restriction not to use pandas, is there a way in python csv module where i can use CSV headers to auto make columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using pandas, you could create a dataframe with [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), and then save to a DB with [`to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). You would also have the added benefit of having a rich environment for transforming or preprocessing the data before uploading it.