# Cursor Insert return out of memory errors

Tags: python, mysql

I am a newbie of MySQL. I am using Python Connect to insert over 350,000 rows into a table running on a MySQL 8 database. My Python code look like this.

```
    cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)  
    stmt = "INSERT INTO ......" 
    cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
    cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
```

which returns the following errors:

> [ERROR] [MY-010934] [Server] Out of memory; check if mysqld or some
> other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use
> 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap
> space

If I reduce the inserted rows such as inserting 200,000 rows only, the error disappears. I think there must be some size limit on the MySQL settings, but I don't know which one to change. I tried to manually increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 500MB as many answers said, but the error continues. What should I do? I printed out my system variable about size and it's listed below.

```
| binlog_cache_size                                        | 32768                |
| binlog_row_event_max_size                                | 8192                 |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                                   | 32768                |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size               | 25000                |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size                                  | 8388608              |
| delayed_queue_size                                       | 1000                 |
| histogram_generation_max_mem_size                        | 20000000             |
| host_cache_size                                          | 279                  |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size                            | 134217728            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                                  | 134217728            |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size                            | 25                   |
| innodb_doublewrite_batch_size                            | 0                    |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                                     | 8000000              |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                                 | 84                   |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                                 | 3                    |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size                               | 640000000            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                                   | 16777216             |
| innodb_log_file_size                                     | 50331648             |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size                              | 8192                 |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                                 | 1073741824           |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size                         | 134217728            |
| innodb_page_size                                         | 16384                |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                                  | 300                  |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                                  | 1048576              |
| innodb_sync_array_size                                   | 1                    |
| join_buffer_size                                         | 262144               |
| key_buffer_size                                          | 8388608              |
| key_cache_block_size                                     | 1024                 |
| large_page_size                                          | 0                    |
| max_binlog_cache_size                                    | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size                                          | 1073741824           |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                               | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_heap_table_size                                      | 16777216             |
| max_join_size                                            | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_relay_log_size                                       | 0                    |
| myisam_data_pointer_size                                 | 6                    |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size                                | 9223372036853727232  |
| myisam_mmap_size                                         | 18446744073709551615 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size                                  | 8388608              |
| ngram_token_size                                         | 2                    |
| optimizer_trace_max_mem_size                             | 1048576              |
| parser_max_mem_size                                      | 18446744073709551615 |
| performance_schema_accounts_size                         | -1                   |
| performance_schema_digests_size                          | 10000                |
| performance_schema_error_size                            | 4890                 |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size       | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_size            | 10                   |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size   | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_size        | 10                   |
| performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size      | 10                   |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size        | 10000                |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_size             | 10                   |
| performance_schema_hosts_size                            | -1                   |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size            | 512                  |
| performance_schema_setup_actors_size                     | -1                   |
| performance_schema_setup_objects_size                    | -1                   |
| performance_schema_users_size                            | -1                   |
| preload_buffer_size                                      | 32768                |
| profiling_history_size                                   | 15                   |
| query_alloc_block_size                                   | 8192                 |
| query_prealloc_size                                      | 8192                 |
| range_alloc_block_size                                   | 4096                 |
| range_optimizer_max_mem_size                             | 8388608              |
| read_buffer_size                                         | 131072               |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                                     | 262144               |
| rpl_read_size                                            | 8192                 |
| select_into_buffer_size                                  | 131072               |
| slave_pending_jobs_size_max                              | 134217728            |
| sort_buffer_size                                         | 262144               |
| thread_cache_size                                        | 9                    |
| tmp_table_size                                           | 16777216             |
| transaction_alloc_block_size                             | 8192                 |
| transaction_prealloc_size                                | 4096                 |
```

Comment: Is there a really good reason why you can't split your data into blocks of 5,000 rows and do 7 inserts instead of one?

Comment: I want to make sure all the data in a group (over 300,000 rows) is inserted or none of them should be inserted. On the other hand, I think I could learn something by tackling the problem, rather than working around it.

Comment: @Yuan That is what transactions are for. Start a transaction, and only commit if everything succeeded, and rollback otherwise.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you very much. I checked the transaction example. It could perfectly solve my problem. Just for learning, I still hope any MySQL veteran could give me some hint about adjusting MySQL size limit variables so that I could insert large rows (over 350,000) at once.  I tried increasing some size variables, but it doesn't work. I will close the question if nobody could answer later. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Reducing** `innodb_buffer_pool_size` rather than **increasing** it could solve memory over-usage.

My machine hardware has 1.7 G memory, MySQL use about 23% memory on startup.

When setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100M`, after inserting 400,000 rows of data using `Python MySQL Connector`, MySQL memory usage climbs to 30% and doesn't go down even if the program ended.

However, if I set `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 50M`, the memory still climbs to a 30% level when the Python program running, but soon goes down if the program ended.

Pure experimental finding, maybe some veteran could explain the back reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

As @BoarGules suggested, this solution proved to be a savior for me in mysql out of memory problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7137270/7977550

MySQL 5.7, 6gb ram free , use mysql.connector and "values" in chunks(values) is 2799617 item list.

```
def chunks(data, rows=10000):
    """ Divides the data into 10000 rows each """
    for i in range(0, len(data), rows):
        yield data[i:i+rows]


query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s);"
div_values = chunks(values)  # divide into 10000 rows each
for values in div_values:
    cursor.executemany(query, list(zip(values)))
```