# Is sqlite3 scalable to handle situations like high traffic social networking sites?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Recently I have started learning rails and was a little surprised that the default database is sqlite3.

I have used sqlite3 before for lightweight applications like programs that have their own personal database, embedded databases on iPhone apps and keeping a light database on a embedded system with a microcontroller, but I never thought of using it on a system as a drop in replacement for a more advanced DBMS like mysql.

Can sqlite3 handle being the DBMS for high traffic sites?

Comment: The choice of SQLite as the default database for Rails applications was a mistake that causes no end of trouble (witness the number of "worked at home, doesn't work on Heroku" questions). The default should be a question: what database do you plan to deploy on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the best answer on the subject: [How Scalable is SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998/how-scalable-is-sqlite)

My opinion is no-way would I use sqlite for something as multi-user and persistent-intensive as a social networking site.

Comment: Never mind all the portability issues (GROUP BY behavior, data type issues, ...) you'll face when trying to move your application away from SQLite at 03:00 with your site in flames all around you.